# Getting the Screen Pixel coordinates of a Rect element

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to get the screen pixel coordinates of a rectangle in SVG via java script.
When the rectangle has been clicked, I can figure out its width, height, x and y position with getBBox().

But these positions are the original positions. I want the screen position.

For example if I manipulate the viewBox of the whole SVG, these getBBox coordinates are not any more the same than the screen pixels. Is there a function or way to get the
coordinates considering the current viewBox and the pixel size of svg element?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Demo: http://phrogz.net/SVG/screen_location_for_element.xhtml

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var pt  = svg.createSVGPoint();
function screenCoordsForRect(rect){
  var corners = {};
  var matrix  = rect.getScreenCTM();
  pt.x = rect.x.animVal.value;
  pt.y = rect.y.animVal.value;
  corners.nw = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
  pt.x += rect.width.animVal.value;
  corners.ne = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
  pt.y += rect.height.animVal.value;
  corners.se = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
  pt.x -= rect.width.animVal.value;
  corners.sw = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
  return corners;
}
```

The magenta squares are absolutely-positioned divs in the HTML element, using screen space coordinates. When you drag or resize the rectangles this function is called and moves the corner divs over the four corners  (lines 116-126). Note that this works even when the rectangles are in arbitrary nested transformation (e.g. the blue rectangle) and the SVG is scaled (resize your browser window).

For fun, drag one of the rectangles off the edge of the SVG canvas and notice the screen-space corners staying over the unseen dots.

Comment: Great answer! Simple and to the point. I would gladly add more points if I could that much useful it is.

Comment: Sorry to bring this question back to life but I'm currently trying to get screen coordinates of an svg element and was curious if X/Y coordinates can be gotten from the example above

Comment: @k.ken That's what the able code gives you. A JavaScript object with four properties, each of which is an SVG Point with x,y coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The coordinates are not relative to the svg right? Just screen coordinates? My question was directed towards getting a single point(middle) for the rectangle knowing its corner coordinates. A quick calculation is to get it using the nw and se coordinate points. That gets the middle coordinate. Thanks for replying again and thanks for posting this answer

Comment: Nowadays you can just use `element.getBoundingClientRect()`

Answer (score 4):

You can also check for the existence of the `elm.getScreenBBox()` method, which does what it sounds like. It's defined in [SVG Tiny 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/svgudom.html#svg__SVGLocatable_getScreenBBox).

[See the files here](http://my.opera.com/MacDev_ed/blog/getting-screen-boundingboxes-in-svg), which include a fallback implementation of `getScreenBBox` that should work in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you Erik for this additional solution

Comment: Blogpost link no longer works - "My Opera" is closed.