# Get Screen Position of SVG inline element in an HTML5 document

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, position, element

I am currently trying to find a technique for ascertaining the actual screen position of a inline SVG path element in an html5 document.

I'd like to obtain this information using only javascript (ie. not jQuery) and use it to set the position of another element in the html file (a "target-tracking" div).

The function call will not be triggered by a mouse event, but rather page load & resize.

My *understanding* is that the findPos function below (from my research here) should get the total offset of the SVG path, which should then equal it's actual screen position.  However, it just seems to return the position the the container div.

As a quick aside - I unfortunately do not presently have the resources to learn programming the right way.  My hope is to someday land a entry-level position and learn in a more efficient and structured way than internet searches, combing the arcane standards, w3schools/codecademy/etc, and, frankly, a hell of a lot of shotgunning.  Please excuse any indecent noobity.   =)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>

*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html, body{ background-color: #000000; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; text-align: center;}


#testDiv{ background-color: #333333; width:81%; margin: 5em auto; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; }

#testSVG{ background-color: #555555; width:73%; margin: 20px;}

#testGroup{ background-color: orange;}

#testPath{ fill: green;}

#testTrack{ background-color: red; width: 10px; height: 10px; position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; z-index: 5;}

#testDisplay{ width: 60%; height: 60%; background-color: #DDDDDD; margin: auto; padding: 1em;}


#buttons{ background-color: #cccccc; color: blue; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; position: fixed; margin: 0 auto; padding: 1em; text-align: center;}

#buttons button{ padding: .7em;}    

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="testDiv">
<svg id="testSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 75 75">
    <g id="testGroup">
        <path id="testPath" d="M45.694,15.319c6.639,2.489-1.897,18.111-1.897,18.111s17.622-0.31,17.525,4.955
            C61.222,43.65,43.51,42.18,43.51,42.18s4.793,15.838,0.702,18.197c-4.089,2.36-9.112-15.766-9.112-15.766S21.742,53.883,18.012,50.9
            c-2.783-3.219,12.181-13.539,12.181-13.539S14.477,27.5,18.927,23.053c4.446-4.447,16.638,7.4,16.638,7.4
            S39.058,12.829,45.694,15.319z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
<div id="testTrack"> </div>
    <div id="testDisplay"> this will be replaced by function test output.</div>
</div>


<div id="buttons">
<button onclick="setNewXY()">test setNewXY()</button>
<button onclick="findPos('testPath')">test findPos() for testPath ID.</button>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" >

function findPos(obj) {
var curleft = curtop = 0;
if (obj.offsetParent) {
  do {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
      return [curleft,curtop];}

     document.getElementById('testDisplay').innerHTML = findPos(testPath);
}


function setNewXY() {
var getPosResult = findPos(testPath).toString();
var makePosArray = getPosResult.split(',');

    document.getElementById('testTrack').style.left = makePosArray[0] + "px"; 
    document.getElementById('testTrack').style.top = makePosArray[1] + "px";
}   

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the Screen Pixel coordinates of a Rect element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834298/getting-the-screen-pixel-coordinates-of-a-rect-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "path" element is a svg element not a html classic element so you don't have css offsets for it, you describe them.

Check this for what you need: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html.
For that offsets you should check the moveto part of description.

```
    d="M45.694,15.319c6.639,2.489-1.897,18.111-1.897,18.111s17.622-0.31,17.525,4.955
        C61.222,43.65,43.51,42.18,43.51,42.18s4.793,15.838,0.702,18.197c-4.089,2.36-9.112-15.766-9.112-15.766S21.742,53.883,18.012,50.9
        c-2.783-3.219,12.181-13.539,12.181-13.539S14.477,27.5,18.927,23.053c4.446-4.447,16.638,7.4,16.638,7.4
        S39.058,12.829,45.694,15.319z"
```

M = moveto, absolute positioning. So your path starts at x=45.694, y=15.319 then it follows the rest.

Comment: Thanks zozo, that was a helpful read.  
I'm afraid my roadblock might have more to do with finding the position of the SVG after things like percentage-based widths and centering.  
  
I am still in search of some way to ascertain the rendered position of an SVG's inner element in terms of screen position.  I'm just not sure how to proceed, through matrix transforms, some sort of SVG-specific DOM transversing to find the position of a centered SVG or something I have yet to stumble across.  
  
Again additional leads are appreciated!

Comment: You can get the svg position (give it an id and get offsets) then add to it the offsets of element. Eventually a multiplier might be need but shouldn't be a tragedy. I can't understand exactly what do you want to do so sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: apologies for my delayed response, i've just now set up email notifications.

your comment was helpful (i don't have enough rep here yet to upvote it!)  but the shapes i am using are complex and the starting point doesn't always reflect top left (in the example, it's the base of one of the flower petals).

Comment: You can calculate the top position. Get the position of the starting point and then get the sum of the negative Ys. The top position is the starting position - sum. Sorry for delay :P Christmass+new year = drunk as hell.