# How to get position of a centered SVG element

Tags: svg, position

How can one get the screen-pixel position of a centered SVG element?

eg: if an SVG element is given 100% width, and center's a contained g - what approach can get the actual screen position of g?

Comment: Hi Dave, just noticed my question was edited, but I'm not sure what was adjusted - feel free to let me know and I'll put the knowledge to any future questions I might ask here.

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8587364/revisions) for what was changed.

Comment: Duplicate of [Getting the Screen Pixel coordinates of a Rect element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834298/getting-the-screen-pixel-coordinates-of-a-rect-element); the same technique works regardless of the element involved, or how it is placed.