# Get the bounds of a rotated SVG element in screen pixels?

Tags: javascript, svg, bounding-box

I'm trying to find the best way to get the bounding box of an arbitrary SVG element in screen pixels, in order to overlay an HTML element correctly. My approach so far has been to use `.getBBox()` and `.getCTM()` to retrieve the object's bounding box and transform matrix, then apply the transform to the bounding box points as described in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834298/getting-the-screen-pixel-coordinates-of-a-rect-element).

```
// get the element
var el = $(selector)[0],
    pt = $(selector).closest('svg')[0].createSVGPoint();

// get the bounding box and matrix
var bbox = el.getBBox(),
    matrix = el.getScreenCTM();

pt.x = bbox.x;
pt.y = bbox.y;
var nw = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);
pt.x += bbox.width;
pt.y += bbox.height;
var se = pt.matrixTransform(matrix);

// make a div in the screen space around the object
var $div = $('<div class="bbox"/>').css({
        left: nw.x,
        top: nw.y,
        width: se.x - nw.x,
        height: se.y - nw.y
    })
    .appendTo('body');
```

You can see my test here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/zr2jX/

However, as the test shows, this approach seems to fail when there's a rotation included in the transform - it looks like the bounding box is calculated pre-rotation, so getting the corners of the rotated bounding box isn't working.

**How can I properly calculate the non-rotated bounding box of the transformed elements?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some research, here are the best options I've found:

- [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) seems to work well for SVG elements in modern browsers, and is quite fast, but results may vary somewhat from platform to platform (especially if you have a substantial stroke width). However, to @Sergiu's point, this does not account for changes in shape, and gives you the bounds of the rotated bounding box, not the actual path or object, so it can be quite imprecise - [see criticism here](http://phrogz.net/getboundingclientrect-is-lame-for-svg). Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenbenner/6M5zf/
- My main goal was to get positional corners and midpoints of the bounding rectangle, and in the end I decided that using the rotated bounding box might even be preferable to the "real" bounding box of a rotated shape. I was able to do this using the approach above, and then cycling the points to get as close as possible to N,S,E,W positions. You can see my example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/sPtzV/

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible, because skew and rotation involve a **profile change**, or how the shape's projections on the two axes look.

You could compute the transformation matrix that would ignore the rotation part of the CTM, but then you don't have any guarantee that the new BBox will still surround your rotated element. For example, if you have a circle, the rotation doesn't affect the dimensions of the bounding box. If, on the other hand, you have a diamond as the base path, and you rotate it by 45 degrees, so that in the end it is just a square, the bounding box is different: originally you were measuring the diagonal, and now you have to obtain a bounding box that measures the side length. No matter how you use the CTM, you can't take into account the change in shape.

So, the rotation is actually quite important, ignoring it is not an option; but just the local bounding box and the transformation matrix don't tell anything about how the shape profile changes when it's rotated.

Comment: That's a good point, but a) it would be best if I could get the basic bounds of the rotated bounding box, and b) I'm hoping there's something I don't know in the SVG API that can give me a new bounding box based on the transformed shape.

Comment: In theory you could use [checkEnclosure](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__checkEnclosure) to do a kind of binary search for the smallest rectangle that fully encloses your element. Unfortunately [it's not implemented in Firefox yet](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501421).