# A generic JS function to move any SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg

Considering this example with 2 circles (red and blue):

```
<svg width="500px" height="500px">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" id="redcircle" />
  <g transform="translate(200,-20)">
    <g transform="scale(2)">
      <g transform="rotate(45)">
        <g transform="translate(5,10)">
          <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" id="bluecircle" />
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I wonder if there is a way to write a generic function like:

```
function move(selection){
  // ???
}
```

That would allow to write `move("#redcircle")` or `move("#bluecircle")` which would visually move the target element 100px to the right (for example).

Answer (score 8):

See this jsfiddle

```
function moveSection(idStr, xOffset, yOffset) {
var domElemnt = document.getElementById(idStr);
    if (domElemnt) {
        var transformAttr = ' translate(' + xOffset + ',' + yOffset + ')';
        domElemnt.setAttribute('transform', transformAttr);
    }
}
moveSection("bluecircle", 50, 20);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dKxZt/4/

It uses translate to move the element.

See this demo here to implement drag of an SVG element: [Getting the Screen Pixel coordinates of a Rect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834298/getting-the-screen-pixel-coordinates-of-a-rect-element)

Comment: the rotation is the problem here... or any other translation from a parent element will also change the behaviour. Maybe you could copy and remove the element and add it to the SVG's root element?

Comment: That's the point. I actually want to write a drag() method so that the selected shape would follow the mouse.
Copying won't help because I would have to reposition it and that's as hard.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834298/getting-the-screen-pixel-coordinates-of-a-rect-element

Answer (score -2):

It is the drag and drop SVG with JQuery
Hope this link can help 
http://www.codedread.com/blog/archives/2005/12/21/how-to-enable-dragging-in-svg/

This is the demo 
http://www.codedread.com/dragtest.svg

Comment: Link is now broken. You have to post the code snippet in your answer in order to help the community!