# How to create stretchable svg shapes

Tags: svg, d3.js

How to create workflow components with stretchable feature of different shapes like in this link http://rigrr.rapilabs.com/

I have implement a sample using d3 such as draggable circle but I don't know how to achieve stretching of shapes

```js
var boxWidth = 600;
var boxHeight = 400;

var box = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'box')
  .attr('width', boxWidth)
  .attr('height', boxHeight);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('dragstart', function() {
    circle.style('fill', 'red');
  })
  .on('drag', function() {
    circle.attr('cx', d3.event.x)
      .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
  })
  .on('dragend', function() {
    circle.style('fill', 'black');
  });

var circle = box.selectAll('.draggableCircle')
  .data([{
    x: (boxWidth / 2),
    y: (boxHeight / 2),
    r: 25
  }])
  .enter()
  .append('svg:circle')
  .attr('class', 'draggableCircle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .call(drag)
  .style('fill', 'black');
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: If you've tried something already, please post some code as a starting point. Then, rather than asking the broad question "how to create stretchable shapes", you can ask "how do I make the circle in this example stretchable?".

Comment: This is quite complex really, I'd break it down into smaller chunks and decide how you want to drag/stretch shapes. What happens if you want to stretch a circle ? Do you put a scale on it, or change it into an ellipse ? If its a rect, do you select a corner and drag it, how do you want to decide to stretch vs drag ? Its quite a big question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it - add a group and add the element and a ghost of the element behind the element but with a slightly bigger size. This element can be used for resizing.

I've added this to your circle move code in the below snippet

```js
        var boxWidth = 600;
        var boxHeight = 400;

        var box = d3.select('body')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('class', 'box')
          .attr('width', boxWidth)
          .attr('height', boxHeight);

        var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
          .on('drag', function() {
            g.selectAll('*')
              .attr('cx', d3.event.x)
              .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
          })

        var resize = d3.behavior.drag()
          .on('drag', function() {
            g.selectAll('.resizingContainer')
              .attr('r', function(c) {
                return Math.pow(Math.pow(this.attributes.cx.value - d3.event.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.attributes.cy.value - d3.event.y, 2), 0.5) + 6;
              });
            g.selectAll('.draggableCircle')
              .attr('r', function(c) {
                return Math.pow(Math.pow(this.attributes.cx.value - d3.event.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.attributes.cy.value - d3.event.y, 2), 0.5);
              });
          })

        var g = box.selectAll('.draggableGroup')
          .data([{
            x: (boxWidth / 2),
            y: (boxHeight / 2),
            r: 25
          }])
          .enter()
          .append('g')

         g
          .append('svg:circle')
          .attr('class', 'resizingContainer')
          .attr('cx', function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr('cy', function(d) {
            return d.y;
          })
          .attr('r', function(d) {
            return d.r + 6;
          })
          .style('fill', '#999')
          .call(resize);

        g
          .append('svg:circle')
          .attr('class', 'draggableCircle')
          .attr('cx', function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr('cy', function(d) {
            return d.y;
          })
          .attr('r', function(d) {
            return d.r;
          })
          .call(drag)
          .style('fill', 'black')
```

```css
        .box {
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-radius: 10px;
        }
        .resizingContainer {
          cursor: nesw-resize;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: one quick question, Is it possible for a user to type text into a shape? Lets a svg shape. From the link I have provided in the question, if you see I can type into a shape

Comment: It'll probably be better to use a normal HTML input box for that. You can append it to the SVG using foreignObject (but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work in IE) or find the positions of the SVG element or go for the easy way and just open up a dialog box :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your idea of "streching" is but you can look at transforms such as scale and skew.

transform="skewX(50)" 
transform="skewY(50)"

Comment: Phrogz has a good demo that shows how to resize elements dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834298/getting-the-screen-pixel-coordinates-of-a-rect-element