# How can I get rect coordinates d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanna know if it's possible to get rectangles x,y coordinates in d3.
As per attached image I wanna know where are: A, B, C, D.

[image]

actually I can get the rotation and with translation I get "C" point. But I need to get also other points.

Here Below you can see a portion of code that get each rect on the curve (classed locked) and create an object with all parameters:

```
var elements = [];
  var num_locked = $('.locked').length;   

  $('.locked').each(function(){

    var matrix = $(this).css('transform');
    console.log('actual: '+matrix);
    if(matrix !== 'none') {
        var values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
        var a = values[0];
        var b = values[1];
        var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
    } else { var angle = 0; }
    var rotate = (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;


    var m = parseInt($(this).css('transform').split(',')[4])+','+parseInt($(this).css('transform').split(',')[5]);
    var close = JSON.parse("[" + m + "]");
    p = closestPoint(para_esterna.node(), close);


    elements.push({
      width:$(this).attr('width'),
      height:$(this).attr('height'),
      transform_x: parseInt($(this).css('transform').split(',')[4]),
      transform_y: parseInt($(this).css('transform').split(',')[5]),
      rotation: rotate,
      p_x: p[0],
      p_y: p[1]
    });


  });
```

Comment: Could you share the code you already have ?

Comment: @MehdiElFadil yes now I edit the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the Screen Pixel coordinates of a Rect element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834298/getting-the-screen-pixel-coordinates-of-a-rect-element)

Comment: @altocumulus thanks for your answer. Now I take a look on this link.

Comment: @altocumulus no this can't help me because all modern browsers (I tested with chrome and firefox) don't know this method getScreenCTM